# Sort element in a new array with twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

After looping over bets with twig i receive those elements, i need to make an table tr line for those who have the same combination. How can i make  a new array with twig where elements are grouped by the same combination ?

```
ReportBetEntity^ {#1486 ▼
  -id: 116596140
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 102
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1487 ▶}
  -betSubType: "ordre"
  -combination: "12-4-13-8-14"
  -odds: 7858.0
}
ReportBetEntity^ {#1488 ▼
  -id: 116596142
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 102
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1489 ▶}
  -betSubType: "ordre"
  -combination: "12-13-4-8-14"
  -odds: 7858.0
}
ReportBetEntity^ {#1559 ▼
   -id: 116597169
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 26
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1560 ▶}
  -betSubType: "ordre"
  -combination: "12-4-13-8-14"
  -odds: 12733.0
}
ReportBetEntity^ {#1561 ▼
  -id: 116597171
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 26
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1562 ▶}
  -betSubType: "ordre"
  -combination: "12-13-4-8-14"
  -odds: 12733.0
}
ReportBetEntity^ {#1490 ▼
  -id: 116596141
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 102
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1491 ▶}
  -betSubType: "desordre"
  -combination: "12-4-13-8-14"
  -odds: 211.0
}
ReportBetEntity^ {#1565 ▼
  -id: 116597170
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 26
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1566 ▶}
  -betSubType: "desordre"
  -combination: "12-4-13-8-14"
  -odds: 263.6
}
ReportBetEntity^ {#1492 ▼
   -id: 116596143
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 102
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1493 ▶}
  -betSubType: "bonus4"
  -combination: "12-4-13-8"
  -odds: 7.0
}
 ReportBetEntity^ {#1569 ▼
  -id: 116597172
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 26
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1570 ▶}
  -betSubType: "bonus4"
  -combination: "12-4-13-8"
  -odds: 6.2
 }
ReportBetEntity^ {#1494 ▼
  -id: 116596144
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 102
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1495 ▶}
  -betSubType: "bonus3"
  -combination: "12-4-13"
  -odds: 3.2
 }
ReportBetEntity^ {#1573 ▼
   -id: 116597173
  -raceId: 4620200121103
  -bookmakerId: 26
  -betType: ReportBetTypeEntity^ {#1574 ▶}
  -betSubType: "bonus3"
  -combination: "12-4-13"
  -odds: 3.1
}
```

I don't have access to the data i receive so i have to do that in twig, i know i can merge element with the merge filter but i don't know how to proceed in this case

Comment: Are you able to extend `twig`?

Comment: depending on your twig & symfony version, you might be able to use the sort filter: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/sort.html . that in combination with remembering the previous combination (if it's different, open a new row, essentially).

Comment: i don't think sort could work here because "combinaton" is not only numerical so i wonder how it can sort it. But yes i can extend twig if its necessary.

Comment: I'd just write a filter then to solve this

Comment: Could you provide an example im not familiar with filters ?